# Testing response time

Tags: jmeter, swagger, performance-testing, katalon-studio, web-api-testing

I am trying to make a request where it returns very big data. When I make a request from Katalon Studio or JMeter, it gives me a response after 7-8 seconds. But from swagger when I try to make same request as I did from katalon studio it needs 2-3 minutes to give me the data and also if it needs more than 2-3 minutes, page dies.

Can you help me understanding, why I get response from swagger so slow and from Katalon so fast? I think the problem is in showing the big information ?

In JMeter data is not shown fully.

I can provide everything what is needed.

This is the data from JMeter.
[image]

Comment: Your first statement states that you are getting the response within 7 seconds in JMeter. However, the screenshot that you shared shows a total time of 21 seconds. If you are fetching a very large response body, JMeter will limit it while displaying the data in tree view (although it properly downloaded the request). Also, Swagger is a UI tool that has to parse the incoming response and refresh the screen to load the entire data. JMeter does not do that

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. Now I understood what was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. With regards to "swagger so slow" - most probably it's your browser issue, it might fail to render big amounts of data. Consider using a command-line tool like [Curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) which can output the response as plain text or save it into a file
2. With regards to  `JMeter data is not shown fully`, by default JMeter limits the data coming from the server to save memory to 10 megabytes, it's controllable via the [`view.results.tree.max_size` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous). If you want to see the full response data in the [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) - add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   view.results.tree.max_size=0
   ```

   or provide the above parameter via `-J` command-line argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jview.results.tree.max_size=0 -t test.jmx ....
   ```

   see [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of setting/overriding them.

   You can also consider using [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener to store the response to a file of your choice.

Comment: Can I calculate how long does it takes to get the full data ? When I execute test case and it finishes, it works slow then because it takes big amount of data.